# I want to know how to send packets from pcap file in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireshark, packet, pcap

In Windows OS, there is a program called "Packet Builder" by ColaSoft. This program has a function to retrieve and retransmit packets captured in Wireshark. I am trying to do the same in Kali Linux. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

low-level: using a bog-normal socket, probably of `AF_PACKET` protocol family to allow you to transmit arbitrary content.

high-level: `tcpreplay` is what I used to do before.

Comment: Presumably you meant `PF_PACKET` rather than `AF_SOCKET` (or `PF_SOCKET` - "PF" stands for "protocol family", whereas "AF" stands for "address family", but the AF_ and PF_ values with similar names have the same numeric value).

Comment: And note that libpcap has had the `pcap_inject()` and `pcap_sendpacket()` routines to send packets using whatever mechanism the OS on which you're running uses.

Comment: But letting `tcpreplay` do the work for you, as suggested by Markus Müller, is much less work than writing your *own* code to read a pcap file and inject packets.

Comment: @user16139739 I meant `AF_PACKET`, actually, thanks! (`PF_PACKET` is news to me, `man 2 socket` says `AF_PACKET` is the right thing)

Comment: Presumably the Berkeley folks wanted to decouple protocol and address families to allow a protocol family to support multiple address families or to allow multiple protocol families to use the same address family.  In practice, that didn't happen, and `PF_xxx` had the same value as `AF_xxx` for all values of "xxx".  The POSIX spec doesn't even define any `PF_` values, just `AF_` values, so I guess the `PF_` values are only for backwards source compatibility.